# How to tell which button I am checking in a function?

Tags: c#, button

I am working on a minesweeper game and I'm stuck with removing the ability to click on a button once it's value has been discovered.So far this is the code:

```
public void verif(int x,int y)
    {

        int i=1;
        if(a[x-1,y-1]==0)
        {
            Lista[x-y].Text=" ";
            verif(x-1,y-1);
        }
        else if(a[x-1,y-1]!=-1)
        {
            c=Convert.ToString(a[x-1,y-1]);
            Lista[x-y].Text=c;
            i=i*x+y;
```

The i variable is used to track the number of the button that I am checking right now.The problem is I don't know how to use it because the way I did it was I added the buttons in a list

```
List<Button> Lista = new List<Button>();
Lista.Add(b1);
Lista.Add(b2);
Lista.Add(b3);
Lista.Add(b4);
Lista.Add(b5);
```

I know this is probably not the best way to do it but it's the only way I could wrap my head around it.

UPDATE: I rewrote the program using 2D arrays and now all the weirdness is gone thank you all for the help!

Comment: Why not pass the button into the routine and either use `.Name` or the `Tag` property to figure out which button you are calling this with?

Comment: And using a 2D array instead of a list is probably a lot more intuitive and easy.

Comment: I know which button i am calling this with.The problem is that say i find a button that has 1 bomb around it.I make it show 1 but then i have to close it .It's not the button i'm calling this with..it's the buttons that get called after. Say i click on the button at a[2,2] which is my button nr 5 . It then goes on to the button at a[1,1] first and say it is marked with a 1 because it has 1 bomb.I want to close it after that but i don't know which button it is.Hope this explains my problem better.Also i have about 16 buttons but i only showed 5 because of space.

Comment: Is there a reason you wouldn't assign a click-event handler to the buttons? The event-handling system would tell you what object triggered the event. With this architecture, you'd probably want something like a `Hashtable` or `Dictionary` to associate the coordinates back with each button.

Comment: I have managed to code it more clean with a 2D array of buttons and now it's a lot easier to find out what buttons i'm actually clicking on using 2 nested for's and checking for the object in the array.